# How do I Convert Python Dict to JSON in a Multi-Threaded Fashion

Tags: python, json

I have a number of large files with many thousands of lines in python dict format. I'm converting them with json.dumps to json strings.

```
import json
import ast

mydict = open('input', 'r')
output = open('output.json', "a")

for line in mydict:
        line = ast.literal_eval(line)
        line = json.dumps(line)
        output.write(line)
        output.write("\n")
```

This works flawlessly, however, it does so in a single threaded fashion. Is there an easy way to utilize the remaining cores in my system to speed things up?

Edit:

Based on the suggestions I've started here with the multiprocessing library:

```
import os
import json
import ast
from multiprocessing import Process, Pool

mydict = open('twosec.in', 'r')

def info(title):
        print title
        print 'module name:', __name__
        print 'parent process: ', os.getppid()
        print 'process id:', os.getpid()

def converter(name):
        info('converter function')
        output = open('twosec.out', "a")
        for line in mydict:
                line = ast.literal_eval(line)
                line = json.dumps(line)
                output.write(line)
                output.write("\n")

if __name__ == '__main__':
        info('main line')
        p = Process(target=converter, args=(mydict))
        p.start()
        p.join()
```

I don't quite understand where Pool comes into play, can you explain more?

Comment: The bottleneck here is probably the I/O, so I doubt you’ll get any benefits from using multiple threads to do the *conversion*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the code above in a function that takes as its single argument a filename and that writes the json to an output file.

Then create a `Pool` object from the `multiprocessing` module, and use `Pool.map()` to apply your function in parallel to the list of all files. This will automagically use all cores on your CPU, and because it uses multiple processes instead of threads, you won't run into the global interpreter lock.

**Edit:** Change the main portion of your program like so;

```
  if __name__ == '__main__':
     files = ['first.in', 'second.in', 'third.in'] # et cetera
     info('main line')
     p = Pool()
     p.map(convertor, files)
     p.close()
```

Of course you should also change `convertor()` to derive the output name from the input name!

Below is a complete example of a program to convert DICOM files into PNG format, using the [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) program

```
"Convert DICOM files to PNG format, remove blank areas."

import os
import sys # voor argv.
import subprocess
from multiprocessing import Pool, Lock

def checkfor(args):
    try:
        subprocess.check_output(args, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    except CalledProcessError:
        print "Required program '{}' not found! exiting.".format(progname)
        sys.exit(1)

def processfile(fname):
    size = '1574x2048'
    args = ['convert', fname, '-units', 'PixelsPerInch', '-density', '300', 
            '-crop', size+'+232+0', '-page', size+'+0+0', fname+'.png']
    rv = subprocess.call(args)
    globallock.acquire()
    if rv != 0:
        print "Error '{}' when processing file '{}'.".format(rv, fname)
    else:
        print "File '{}' processed.".format(fname)
    globallock.release()

## This is the main program ##
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        path, binary = os.path.split(sys.argv[0])
        print "Usage: {} [file ...]".format(binary)
        sys.exit(0)
    checkfor('convert')
    globallock = Lock()
    p = Pool()
    p.map(processfile, sys.argv[1:])
    p.close()
```

Comment: I've made an edit based on your suggestion, however It's just a start, I'm still not sure where/how to implement Pool

Comment: I've tried a few more things "above" but I still can't seem to get it to work. Can you explain how to use Pool.map() more?

Comment: I added as an example a script that I use for converting images in parallel. I hope you find it useful. Note that by default, Pool will only create as many worker processes as you have cores. If you want more processes, you need to tell that when you create the Pool. See the documnetation.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of an easy way for you to get a speedup from multithreading, but if any sort of speedup is really what you want then I would recommend trying the `ujson` package instead of `json`.  It has produced very significant speedups for me, basically for free.  Use it the same way you would use the regular `json` package.

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ujson/

Comment: Thats quite a speedy json module: http://pushingtheweb.com/2011/03/ultra-fast-json-encoding-decoding-python/

Comment: I do see a small improvement with ujson, about 3 seconds shaved off the 1.23 min 200MB conversion. However that's only a 5 minute savings off of a 2TB file "yes some of the files are that large"

Comment: Right, well then I would agree with @poke that the bottleneck here is likely disk IO, and you won't see a significant improvement regardless of how many processors or better algorithms you throw at the problem.  The only way to improve your speed here would be to get a hard drive with a faster read speed, such as an SSD or a RAID configuration.